# iPhone - Prevent a navigation bar from pushing down a subview

Tags: iphone

In 'iPhone', how can I prevent a navigation bar from pushing down a subview?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the behavior of the view?  Is the subview getting moved around when you push the view, or is it disappearing altogether?

Comment: It doesn't seems me a problem statement, please elaborate the issue which you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you want your view to be under the nav bar, then you should set `wantsFullScreenLayout` property of a viewController you push into nav bar to `YES`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the subview's dimensions are larger than what is available in a navigation controller due to the top bar. Best way to deal with this would probably be to start with the correct dimensions in the first place. However what may be of help to you is the autoresizesSubviews value:

```
secondViewController *aViewController = [[secondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
aViewController.view.autoresizesSubviews = FALSE; 

UINavigationController *theNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:aViewController];
[self.window addSubview:theNavController.view];
```

obviously this will cut off a portion of the screen on the bottom.